# How to get the new width and height of View after ScaleAnimation

Tags: android, android-animation, android-imageview

I used a `ScaleAnimation` to resize my `ImageView`. But after the animation is complete, how can I get the dimension of my `ImageView` or the bitmap in that.
Thanks

Here is my code:

```
ScaleAnimation animation = new ScaleAnimation(m_oldZoomRatio, m_currentZoomRatio, m_oldZoomRatio, m_currentZoomRatio);

        animation.setFillAfter(true);
        animation.setFillEnabled(true);
        animation.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
            }

            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
            }

            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            }
        });
        m_child.startAnimation(animation);
```

Where `m_oldZoomRatio != m_currentZoomRatio`.

I can see my view changes its layout while running. But when get its width and height, I receive the value in original when the view is created.

Comment: If you've got the solution then please share it with me if possible?

Answer (score 1):

try to use animation listener where on animation end you can change the width and height

```
  <animation-object>.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() 
     {

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation arg0) {
            img.getWidth();
                img.getHeight();
                  //OR 
                 int h=img.getLayoutParams().height;
                 int w=img.getLayoutParams().width;
                // For changing actual height and width
             view.getLayoutParams().width = newWidth; 
               view.getLayoutParams().height =    newHeight; 
view.requestLayout();

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation arg0) {


        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation arg0) {


        }

     });
```

Comment: thank for your reply. But my problem is to get the dimension (not to set it as your suggest).

Comment: To get the dimension you can use getHeight() , getWidth() function...just edited in answer

Comment: thank you. But both of them return the original dimension of the view before the ScaleAnimation (but on the screen my ImageView is already change its size).

Comment: okie, I tried and what I get that it actually not changing the height and width, it is just animation which fills the screen, actual height and width are same before and after. If you want to change actual the height and width , oyu need to specify the same in animation_end function